# Accessing a PDB file on Android Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, palm-os

I'm an android developer trying to explore some databases. Normally the sqlite database is about the only database that I see around in Android .

Recently I've stumbled across an app that is running on .pdb database files which piqued my interest.

I've downloaded the .pdb files but I cannot seem to access or read the files normally. I'm very curious about the .pdb files and why is not sqlite files ?

Anyone has any ideas ? THanks !

Comment: What do you see when you open the file with regular text editor?

Comment: There are 80+ pdb rules in total split into two different groups of pdb files , one of which is named file_00x.pdb (which opens up to be gibberish) and second group of files named file_00x_strings.pdb (which opens up to be html annotations with English texts) .

Comment: My apologies for a truncated msg as i was travelling. There is a typo in the above msg , 80+ pdb files , not rules. As described earlier , from my limited understanding .pdb files is also used for some ebooks which makes sense for android apps to use it as a format for quick browsing. But I just couldn;t put anything together to make it readable ... any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2):

PDB files are [PalmOS databases](http://goo.gl/TjSI0). There is some Java code floating around for using them, such as:

[Palm Database (PDB) files in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657222/palm-database-pdb-files-in-java)

As to why that particular project elected to use PDB files, you would have to ask its author.