# How can I read/convert/decrypt PDB database files that are handled by Android apps in a readable format (possibly in Python)?

Tags: android, python, database, encryption

I want to access the text of a bilingual Dictionary, which is distributed as Android app.
The apk file itself does not contain the database with the words of the dictionary, but the app obtains the relevant information from a database downloaded in the cache which appears to be a pdb format.

I did a quick search and it seems that pdb can mean a lot of things. I tried to open it but it's encrypted (I was hoping to find some xml friendly code, which is how it should be).

How can I access it, read it (possibly in Python, which is possible if I turn it into some xml-friendly format), decrypt it? is there any way?

Comment: I suspect - but I'm not sure - that they could be database format of [this type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657222/palm-database-pdb-files-in-java)

yet those programs are in Java and I have no idea how to make them work with pyhton

Comment: update: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDB_%28Palm_OS%29) seems to be the format 

I'm trying to compile [jpilot](http://www.jpilot.org/) but with no success..